# Implementing equals/hashCode using a referenced ManyToOne entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, identity

Assume we have following JPA Entities:

```
class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Let's assume a Child can uniquely be identified by its name on the Parent (combination of both). So, Parent and name can be considered as the business key of a Child.

I am unsure now what the best approach would be to implement equals (and hashCode) on the class Child.

**Reference the id of the application**

Since the Application proxy will be loaded and its id will be set on the proxy so the Application entity itself would not be initialized:

> ```
> public boolean equals (Object o) {
>     //null check, instanceof check ...
>     return new EqualsBuilder().append(getName(), other.getName())
>             .append(getParent().getId(), other.getParent().getId())
>             .isEquals();
> ```
>
> }

This will do the trick but I see some downsides as well. First (minor), an extra not null check on the parent would probably be advisable which makes your equals methods less compound.
Next (less minor), This would required hibernate to access the properties rather than the fields; so, I would need to set the annotations on the getters instead of on the fields. This is something I can live with personally but the habit in the current project is to put the annotations on field level.

**Don't use the referenced entity for evaluating equality**

Ok, but then I need something else. I don't want to use the id of the Child (bad practice) which leaves me with only 1 option: using a separate property for this, like a UUID. I have nothing against the use of UUID's but of course only if there is no other option available.

My questions are:

1. Did I miss an option?
2. What, in your opinion, would be the advised way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get why you would have to put annotations on the getter rather than the field. And if equals is correctly implemented on the parent, you could just compare the parents rather than their ids, which avoids the null check.

Comment: Why would this implementation require annotations on the getters rather than the fields?

Comment: @JB Nizet & Tom: if the annotation is put on the field (id) then getId() would cause the proxy to be initialized. There is a [hibernate bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3718) concerning this. See also [this explanation](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/06/jpa-implementation-patterns-field-access-vs-property-access/).

Comment: there is no proxy (or it's always initialized) since the association is eager fetched.

Comment: @JB, sorry, was mistake should be LAZY, I corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility would be to add another field containing the foreign key to the parent which can then be used in the equals and hashCode methods without fetching the referenced entity:

```
@Column(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String parentId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Interesting, did not think this would be possible. Have you ever done this before?

Comment: TheStijn: Yes, this works at least with toplink essentials and hibernate.

Comment: Interesting. If this was pure SQL, i would make the primary key of the child table a composite natural key comprising the parent's ID and the name. I didn't think there was any way to do that in JDBC, but this would allow exactly that - map parent_id to the parent field, and also to a string field in a composite key. Maybe.

Comment: Took a while before I got around to it but it works just as promised. Tx.

Comment: Interesting solution, but for non-persisted Parents, we get the same problem than with using the id as a business key: when creating a new Parent(); and assigning it setParent(p); the parentId is not set, and the equals() and hashCode() methods do not work.

Comment: You should then have public void setParent(Parent p) { this.parent = p; this.parentId = p.getId(); }

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of the EntityManagerFactory (and if you can get hold of the EntityManager, EntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory() is one way to do it), another way to get the parent's ID is with:

```
emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(parent);
```

You'd still need a null check, though.

Comment: Does that really avoid fetching the referenced entity from the db?

Comment: I guess the Hibernate version of the above would be `Serializable id = ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier()`. But I don't like this approach, feels wrong. Also, the entity here might even not be a proxy which is another check you have to do.

Comment: I think in JPA, it doesn't matter if it's a proxy or not. I actually don't know that this won't load the entity, but my guess would be that it doesn't. I agree that it's more of a hack than a solution.